# Does having ZoneId and ZoneOffset at the same time make sense?

Tags: java, date, utc, timezone-offset, zone

I'm a little bit confused of possibility in Java to have ZoneId and ZoneOffset in date at the same time
For example, does the date `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00+01:00[UTC-8]` make sense? What time is it in UTC?
Is it `+01:00` offset from `UTC-8` timezone, so it's the same as `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00[UTC-7]`?

Answer (score 2):

No `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00+01:00[UTC-8]` is a self contradiction. I doubt that there’s a way to construct a `ZonedDateTime` having this value. Or only by defining your own time zone that has an ID of `UTC-8` and an offset of +01:00 at that point in time.

A `ZonedDateTime` has got both time zone and offset.

I am unsure whether it’s relevant to your question, but one way to study whether we can make a point in time out of a self-contradictory string could be:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00+01:00[Pacific/Pitcairn]"));
```

Output on Java 11:

> 2019-12-31T15:00-08:00[Pacific/Pitcairn]

Pitcairn is at offset -08:00 all year. It seems that `ZonedDateTime` has chosen to trust the offset `+01:00`, so the time is the same as 2019-12-31T23:00 in UTC. It has then converted this time to the offset that it finds right for Pacific/Pitcairn time zone according to the time zone database, giving 15:00 in that time zone.

Edit:

> What time is it in UTC? Is it `+01:00` offset from `UTC-8` timezone,
> so it's the same as `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00[UTC-7]`?

No, it is not the same at all. `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00[UTC-7]` would be the same point in time as 2020-01-01T07:00:00 in UTC, but as I said, we got 2019-12-31T23:00 in UTC, which is 8 hours earlier than what you suggested. The `-08:00` are not used to interpret the point in time, they are only used for conversion.

PS There aren’t any single quotes in `2020-01-01T00:00:00+01:00[UTC-8]`. They are only in a format pattern that you would use for printing and/or parsing such a string.

Comment: But 2020-01-01T00:00:00+01:00[UTC-08:00] works as well on Java 11, so I believe that as I said offset is being applied relative to zoneId, but now the question is why zone id is not being considered in UTC

Comment: @CameronCoob What do you mean “works”? Post some code in your Question. As this Answer correctly explains, `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00+01:00[UTC-8]` is contradictory nonsense.

Comment: @CameronCoob Please see my edit correcting your belief.